# How to implement ranking in Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

I want to implement ranking by using Game Center.

So , I implement like this .

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer
{

    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];


    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *vc,NSError *err){
        [self setLastError:err];
        if ([CCDirector sharedDirector].isPaused){
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
        }
        if (localPlayer.authenticated){
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = YES;

            // get localplayer's score.
            GKLeaderboard *board = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

            // make a query

            board.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
            // I want to get all player's score.
            board.playerScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;


            // set my game category.
            board.category = @"com.nobinobiru.shooting";

            // I want to show top 3 score data.
            board.range = NSMakeRange(1, 3);

            [board loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
                NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",board.localPlayerScore.value];
                [ud setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s] forKey:@"bestScore"];
                if (scores){
                    // I want to 3 items but it returned only 1 item.
                    NSLog(@"score is %@",scores);
                }


            }];

        }else if (vc){
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
            [self presentViewController:vc];
        }

    };
}
```

Then, I create 3 sandbox's user account , and I test it.
But it always only show current user's best score.

I want to show 3 sandbox's data.

I don't know why it happened like that.
My code  works well in not sandbox environment?
Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All. 
It works perfectly after 6 hours...

I think that the reason why it happened is my created game center account was not reflect immediately.